# How to send enter to input in protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumberjs

I am struggling with keyup.enter event on input search  in my protractor/cucumber test (angular 2)

I was trying:

```
input_search.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER) // also with Key.RETURN
.then(() => { ...  });
```

and this:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform() // also with Key.RETURN
.then(() => { ...  });
```

but still I can't execute **keyup.enter** event on my search_input.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
                    [(ngModel)]="phrase"  
                    (blur)="onBlur()" 
                    (focus)="onFocus()"
                    (keyup.enter)="search(phrase)"
                     id="search_input"
                    />
```

I can do it when I am clicking magnifier... and in normal browser
using ENTER button.

I am using **cucumberjs 0.10.3** with **protractor 3.3.0** on **node v4.3.1** and **angular2-rc-1** .

Comment: whats the error are you getting?

Comment: First, I am sending some keys to search... then I am trying to send enter, but nothing's happening.. my keyup.enter event isn't fired.. Is it possible to get more info than console logs ? I warn that browser.pause() or browser.debugger() isn't working as well...

Comment: I am having this problem too. keyup.enter is not triggered by sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER). For now added a superfluous button to invoke the action and I test on that. Ever found a solution? No error, it just does not trigger the keyup.enter event.